# Appengine Taskqueue Auto Restart in new instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine, instance, task-queue

I am using task queue to handle my requests for long time. I faced one problem in doing this. Sometimes, while task is running, same task was started in another new instance, resulting these two run in parallel which makes duplication of the process what I intended to do in my application.

I am wondering why the same process was running in two different instances simultaneously and what's the reason making app engine to create another instance to serve the same request.

The following info is what my logs says :

`2014-05-16 23:05:39.479 /tasks/handleRequest 200 414808ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=new
0.1.0.2 - - [16/May/2014:10:35:39 -0700] "POST /tasks/handleRequest HTTP/1.1" 200 243 "http://xxxxx.appspot.com/tasks/doThis" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "xxxxx.appspot.com" ms=414808 cpu_ms=11656 cpm_usd=0.022667 queue_name=handleRequestQueue task_name=7287390692361099748 app_engine_release=1.9.4 instance=00c61b117cf4e0fae1562997464c2608f682c5fd`

`2014-05-16 23:05:39.476 /tasks/handleRequest 200 96058ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=new
0.1.0.2 - - [16/May/2014:10:35:39 -0700] "POST /tasks/handleRequest HTTP/1.1" 200 243 "http://xxxxx.appspot.com/tasks/doThis" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "xxxxx.appspot.com" ms=96059 cpu_ms=5763 cpm_usd=0.005221 queue_name=handleRequestQueue task_name=7287390692361099748 app_engine_release=1.9.4 instance=00c61b117c5727320ffc257d7fd1d518c66f76fd`

By looking into the above logs, the same task ran in different instances. Can anybody tell me what was the reason for that and how to avoid that as this creates critical issue in our application.

Any help would be greatly appreciable..!

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a pull or a push queue?

Comment: The docs for task queues do not make any guarantees about tasks being retried, and there may well be a fault that causes a task to run twice.  The docs are pretty clear that you need to ensure tasks are idempotent.  Having said that your  2 tasks appear to have  different referrers are you sure you haven't scheduled the task twice `http://full-tool.appspot.com/tasks/constructDelimitFileOfSrc` and `http://xxxxx.appspot.com/tasks/doThis` . By explicitly naming tasks you can prevent tasks with the same name being queued.

Comment: @ IanGSY, @Tim Hoffman Thanks for your comments. It is push queue only. I am sure that no fault that causes retry the task to run twice. My 2 tasks are from same referrers.`http://xxxxx.appspot.com/tasks/doThis` I edited my question. And I am sure, that is not scheduled form my code.

Comment: You shouldn't edit stuff which can lead to incorrect/misleading info in your question.  Any way you have two issues here.  1.  You code needs to be idempotent and it isn't at the moment and 2. Why is the task running twice.  Fixing item 1 is in my opinion higher priority.

Comment: Note this line in the docs - *When implementing the code for tasks (as worker URLs within your app), it is important to consider whether the task is idempotent. App Engine's Task Queue API is designed to only invoke a given task once; however, it is possible in exceptional circumstances that a task may execute multiple times (such as in the unlikely case of major system failure). Thus, your code must ensure that there are no harmful side-effects of repeated execution.*

Comment: @Tim Hoffman : The referrer in the log for the two tasks is same. Yes, `http://xxxxx.appspot.com/tasks/doThis` is the one which submitted the task to the queue. The first task was started fine but, after some time say, after 5 mints, the same task being triggered in the different instance and they both ran simultaneously up to end. Thanks.